# How to check if clicked element contains element with certain class

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I am writing a Tampermonkey script that should execute some code if a certain button is clicked.

It should check if the clicked button contained an icon **before** it was clicked. I don't know yet if that's even possible. There are many unique buttons that could be clicked.

This is the button:

```html
<a class="btn aao_btn" id="aao_n">
  <span id="available_aao_n" class="label label-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>
```

This is what I got so far. It always returns false

```js
$("a.aao_btn").on("click", function (e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    // Execute if Shift is pressed while clicking (working)
  }
  else {
    if ( $(this).find("span").hasClass("label_danger") ) {
        // Execute if clicked button contains a danger icon
      }
    else {
       // No danger. Currently this is always the outcome.
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Your code should work, there's just one typo, class is `label-danger`, but you are checking `.hasClass("label_danger")`.

Comment: you are searching for a `label_danger` on your javascript but have a `label-danger` class on your span element, Is that exactly how your code is written?

Comment: omg this is embarassing, thx so much for the quick help!
So how do I handle this? Delete this question?

Comment: @harrybowser Been there, done that. I eventually decided to be a hyphen man, and never use underscores, so I never make this mistake. Super easy to miss while looking over code.

Comment: As the button changes because of the click (normal behavior of the website) it doesn't work, how I need it.
Is there a way to check if the button had the icon **before** it was clicked?

Comment: Not sure of the best solution, but one idea would be to add add a .mouseover handler that checks for label_danger and add/removes my_danger_label to mirror it. Then your .click can check for my_danger_label

Comment: @PrestonPHX thx for the idea. got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the typo, this would not check the status **before** the element was clicked. Here is what I ended up with:

```js
var danger_check = false;

$("a.aao_btn").mouseover (function() {
    if ( $(this).find("span.label-danger").length ) {
        danger_check = true;
    }
    else {
        danger_check = false;
    }
});


$("a.aao_btn").on("click", function (e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) {
  }
  else {
    if ( danger_check ) {
        // Do this
      }
    else {
       // Do that

    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( $(this).find("span.label-danger").length ) {
```

Comment: Don't waste time posting answers for typo questions. Just comment and vote to close.

Comment: Answers slow delay the hoover that automatically deletes these questions after they're closed.

Comment: Typo aside, there is a better way to do what was asked

Comment: Ah. Then you should show how to use this in the `if` statement. Many people do it incorrectly.

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. In plain JS it would be `if (this.querySelector('span.label_danger'))`.